# Convert nvarchar data to decimal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-conversion

I have data stored in a `nvarchar(10)` column that I need to convert to `decimal(10,3)`. Each record is a full 10 characters with leading zeros. The last three numbers represent decimals. How do I convert the following example?

```
col1
----------
0000100001
0002507630
0090078607
0258736000
```

Expected Output

```
col1                   col2
-------------------------------
0000100001              100.001
0002507630             2507.630
0090078607            90078.607
0258736000           258736.000
```

I tried using

```
Cast(covert(decimal(10, 3), col1) as Decimal(10, 3)) as col2
```

The output I receive is

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

How do do properly convert this data?

Comment: Divide the inner convert by 1000 in the outer cast.

Comment: Do you have a syntax you could suggest?  When I try to divide by 1000 I am returned with "Incorrect syntax near '/'."

Comment: sidux has posted what I was suggesting as an answer.   It should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE (a NVARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('0000100001'),('0002507630'),('0090078607'),('0258736000');



SELECT a,CAST(CAST(a AS INT)/1000.000  AS DECIMAL(10,3))
FROM @t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST (LEFT(col1, 7) + '.' + RIGHT(col1,3) AS DECIMAL(10,3))
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa84d/3)